# Unable to paste the copied comment in answer in iOS app

Tags: discussion, bug, ios-app

I remember this was working earlier, but now the copied comment text is not pasting in answer box. Anyone else facing this issue?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the sure-fire fix to all these app related bugs is to _not_ use the app...