# Copy and paste do not work in iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

I have noticed that copy and paste do not seem to work correctly in the Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange iOS apps. Comments cannot be copied using standard iOS gestures at all, and other text selected from questions or answers does not paste. When I try to paste this into another app, it does not work either, but seems to be some sort of binary object instead.

Is there another way to copy and paste within the app? It would be very convenient when posting answers. Also, is there a possibility of fixing this in a future version?

I'm almost scared to ask this, given the fairly intense discussion and hate for the app [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android) - I will quite rightly be accused of being an app user!

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368110/unable-to-paste-the-copied-comment-in-answer-in-ios-app) question is somewhat similar, but only got no answers and only one comment advising not to use the app! Otherwise, I find it pretty convenient.

Comment: Bring your pitchforks and torches everybody! We have another horrible app user! Nah really though, I believe that updates/support for the app has been indefinitely discontinued, so even though your bug report is valid, I don't think we'll see anything come of it. I've upvoted though in case in 6-8 years they decide to return and revamp the app they can look through the bugs to see what needs to be changed, and this will be one of the things.

Comment: @DavyM :) Thanks for the info. I’ll try to make the transition to Safari!